# Prevenir remoção de um banco sqlite no Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Tem como prevenir que o banco de dados sqlite seja removido ao desinstalarem a aplicação?

Tenho uma aplicação que pede senha para acesso, a senha é gravada na primeira vez que o usuário inicia o app (sim eu tenho que fazer desse jeito, o usuário tem que registrar essa senha para ter acesso)... A senha é armazenada dentro do banco, mas tem um problema, um usuário mal intencionado pode simplesmente reinstalar a aplicação, fazendo com que apareça o painel de registro de senha ao iniciar aplicação. Ou seja, ele pode registrar uma nova senha pois o banco foi removido ao desinstalar a aplicação!

Como fazer para evitar isso?

Copiar o banco para a pasta Data me parece gambiarra, tenho receio de problema em alguns aparelhos.

Não posso copiar o banco para o sdcard, pois qualquer um sem root poderia abrir.

Já testei o [BackupAgentHelper](http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/backupapi.html) do Android (que foi feito apenas para preferences e não para binários), não funciona com o sqlite

Comment: Eu cheguei a usar o `BackupAgentHelper` para fazer backup do banco. No caso eu fiz backup do arquivo do banco. Mas se você parar pra pensar, isso não adianta. Ele pode apagar os dados do App nas configurações do sistema. Dessa forma se perde tudo: Bancos e Preferences. Talvez tenha que reformular essa forma de persistência. Porque não usa a conta do usuário do dispositivo para gerar um token no seu back-end (com expiração)?

Comment: como funciona isso do token? @Wakim

Comment: Seria tipo um OAuth2, mas acho isso foge do escopo da pergunta. A minha sugestão é usar outra forma de autenticação, sem gravar nada no dispositivo do usuário (esperando que sempre estará disponível). Será que não dá pra atrelar o login do usuário no seu sistema com algo único do dispositivo (IMEI, UUID, conta do google). Não precisa guardar nada, já que essa informação estaria sempre disponível. Seria algo semelhante que o app do Banco do Brasil faz, ele cadastra o dispositivo no sistema deles (por algum identificador do dispositivo). E assume que o dispositivo é "seguro" sempre que eu logar.

Comment: É um aplicativo que protege fotos, então quem usa quer esconder algo ali, ai ele precisa da senha para que somente quem criou a senha possa acessar e ver as fotos, não somente quem tem acesso ao dispositivo como um todo, não uso webservice, é apenas um banco com uma tabela e uma row, que é a row da senha @Wakim

Comment: Entendi. Daria pra fazer backup encriptado, com um bom algoritmo/salt (existem perguntas e respostas boas sobre isso aqui no SO PT), em `sdcard` ou `External Storage`. Além disso, recomendo guardar a senha encriptada no banco, o usuário com root consegue ter acesso ao banco. Essa questão de apagar os dados do app, o usuário tem que estar ciente do que vai acontecer, você não tem como se proteger contra isso. Realmente não tenho muitas ideias de como superar esses problemas, vamos ver se mais alguma pessoa tenha algo. Sobre fazer backup do banco: https://gist.github.com/samuelmtimbo/10566176.

Comment: Já tentei fazer backup usando esta classe, mas não funcionou aqui. Fiz todos os passos, inclusive por a key no androidmanifest e modificar uma tag que nao lembro o nome (apontando para a classe helper), mas eu consegui fazer backup (teste) de um arquivo sharedpreference, será que funciona com sql mesmo? eu não consegui @Wakim

Comment: ps: Ele nem chega a entrar no oncreate(); Para o sharedpreferences eu segui o exemplo que está no site do Google, tentei também usar este exemplo (modificando algumas coisas) para sqlite, mas não funcionou